# How to record inputs when using "For Loop"

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to ask the user to input how many classes they have (x), ask "What are your grades in those classes?" x amount of times, and record all of the inputted grades to use later.

I tried to assign the question to a variable and ask to print the variable, but I get only the last inputted number. I don't want to print the numbers, I want to store them for later so I can add them together. I was just using the print function to see how my numbers would be stored if assigning the variable actually worked. How would I record all the inputted numbers to later add and calculate GPA?

```
numofclasses = int(input("How many honors classes do you have?: "))
for i in range(numofclasses):
  grades = str(input("Enter the unweighted grade from one class "))

print(grades)
```

I want to get all the inputted numbers recorded, but by using the `print` option I only get the last inputted number recorded.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you want to use is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), which is used to container which holds a sequence of datatypes, like integer, characters, etc,

Think of it this way, if you want to use 3 variables in python what would you generally do

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

This works fine, but what if the number of variables is 50, or 100, how many variables will you keep defining, hence you would need a container to store these, which is where a list comes in. So we would just do

```
li = [1,2,3]
```

And access these variables via indexes, which start from 0

```
a[0] #1
a[1] #2
a[2] #3
```

Keeping this in mind, we would do!

```
numofclasses = int(input("How many honors classes do you have?: "))

#List to save all grades, defined by assigning variable to []
all_grades = []
for i in range(numofclasses):

    #Take grades from the user
    grades = input("Enter the unweighted grade from one class ")

    #Append the grades to the list, using list.append function
    all_grades.append(grades)

#Loop through the list to print it
for item in all_grades:
    print(item)

#Print all grades in a single line by joining all items of list in a string
s = " ".join(all_grades)
print(s)
```

And the output will look like

```
How many honors classes do you have?: 3
Enter the unweighted grade from one class A
Enter the unweighted grade from one class B
Enter the unweighted grade from one class C
#All grades in different lines
A
B
C
#All grades in single line
A B C
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Is there a way to add together the inputted grades (A, B, C)?

Comment: If by adding together letters you mean printing all of them in a single line @LilyHebert ? If yes ser my uofated answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there are a couple options that may be suitable.

Printing the input each iteration:

```
numofclasses = int(input("How many honors classes do you have?: "))
for i in range(numofclasses):
    grades = str(input("Enter the unweighted grade from one class "))
    print(grades) # move print to inside of loop
```

Storing the values in a list for printing later:

```
numofclasses = int(input("How many honors classes do you have?: "))
grades = []
for i in range(numofclasses):
    grades.append(str(input("Enter the unweighted grade from one class ")))

print(grades) # will look like ["A", "B", "C", "B"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful response! If I were to use the second option, is there a way for me to add together all the inputted grades (A, B, C, D)?

Comment: Yes, something like print(“, ”.join(grades)) (untested since I’m on mobile, but should be free of typos) the “, “ part says what you want put between items. It can be any string, or even “” (empty string) which would yield ABCD instead of A, B, C, D

Answer (score 0):

Here is how yo do it:

```
class_dict = {}
numOfClasses = input("How many classes do you take? Enter here : ")
for i in range(int(numOfClasses)):
    class_dict["class" + str(i +1)] = input("Enter your grade for class " + str(i +1) + ":  ")

print(class_dict)
```

The above should do it.